# Chrome css issue with table borders

Tags: css, html, html-table, edit

I'm having trouble with opening this in Google Chrome, it always shows unwanted borders. Any advice? Here's my HTML and CSS code:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  font:1em "Glegoo", slab-serif;
}
table, td, th {
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
table {
  width:60%;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px auto 0px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:center;
  empty-cells:hide;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
th {
  background-color:#000;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
td {
  width:20%;
}
td:empty {
  visibility:hidden;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
.edp-bilhetes{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>musicUS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\JoãoCarlos\Desktop\musicUS\main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Glegoo">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="edp-bilhetes">
      <br><br>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <div class "table-hide"><td></td></div>
          <th colspan="7">Dia</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><b>12 de Julho</b></td>
          <td><b>17 de Julho</b></td>
          <td><b>20 de Julho</b></td>
          <td><b>21 de Julho</b></td>
          <td><b>23 de Julho</b></td>
          <td><b>26 de Julho</b></td>
          <td><b>27 de Julho</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="8">Plateia</th>
          <td>VIP</td>  
          <td>50€</td>
          <td>45€</td>
          <td>65€</td>  
          <td>38€</td>
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>50€</td>
          <td>65€</td>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>45€</td>  
          <td>35€</td>
          <td>55€</td>
          <td>33€</td>  
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>45€</td>
          <td>55€</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>35€</td>  
          <td>30€</td>
          <td>45€</td>
          <td>28€</td>  
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>35€</td>
          <td>45€</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>30€</td>  
          <td>-</td>
          <td>35€</td>
          <td>-</td>  
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>30€</td>
          <td>35€</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bancada Poente e Nascente</td>
          <td>-</td>  
          <td>-</td>
          <td>30€</td>
          <td>-</td>  
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bancada Norte</td>
          <td>-</td>  
          <td>-</td>
          <td>25€</td>
          <td>-</td>  
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Plateia em Pé</td>
          <td>25€</td>  
          <td>20€</td>
          <td>25€</td>
          <td>20€</td>  
          <td>30€*</td>
          <td>25€</td>
          <td>30€</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobilidade Condicionada</td>
          <td>B</td>  
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>A</td>  
          <td>*</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>*Bilhete Único</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an extra row and an extra cell and remove border from table and this extra cell, the idea is to dispatch the colspan and rowpan th into 2 different row in order to break them appart:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em"Glegoo", slab-serif;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
table,
table tr:first-of-type td {
  border: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
th {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  width: 20%;
}
.edp-bilhetes {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="edp-bilhetes">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th colspan="8">Dia</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="10">Plateia</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td><b>12 de Julho</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>17 de Julho</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>20 de Julho</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>21 de Julho</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>23 de Julho</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>26 de Julho</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>27 de Julho</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VIP</td>
      <td>50€</td>
      <td>45€</td>
      <td>65€</td>
      <td>38€</td>
      <td>30€*</td>
      <td>50€</td>
      <td>65€</td>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>45€</td>
        <td>35€</td>
        <td>55€</td>
        <td>33€</td>
        <td>30€*</td>
        <td>45€</td>
        <td>55€</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>35€</td>
        <td>30€</td>
        <td>45€</td>
        <td>28€</td>
        <td>30€*</td>
        <td>35€</td>
        <td>45€</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>30€</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>35€</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>30€*</td>
        <td>30€</td>
        <td>35€</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bancada Poente e Nascente</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>30€</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>30€*</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bancada Norte</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>25€</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>30€*</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Plateia em Pé</td>
        <td>25€</td>
        <td>20€</td>
        <td>25€</td>
        <td>20€</td>
        <td>30€*</td>
        <td>25€</td>
        <td>30€</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mobilidade Condicionada</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <p>*Bilhete Único</p>
</div>
```

If i understood :)